# hibernate mapping to a class with a list

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 3 classes as shown below.

```
@Entity
public class Family (  
    @Id
    private String familyName;

    private int size;

    @OneToMany
    protected VehiclesList getVehiclesList()

    // getters and setters
)

public class VehiclesList (
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

    @Transient
    private int totalInsuranceCost

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Vehicle (
    @Id
    private String plateNumber;
    private String model;
    private String color;

    // getters and setters
)
```

I want to create two tables.  First one is "Family" with columns as "size", etc.  This is easy enough.  Second, I want to create a "Vehicle" table with reference to Family.  This table should have the following columns:
    plateNumber
    FamilyName
    model
    color

I would like the Family class to reference the VehiclesList class, so that I can access information from the VehiclesList class.  None of the data in the VehiclesList class will be persisted to the database - only the vehicles.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

`VehicleList` is not an entity so you cannot use `OneToMany` on it.

`totalInsuranceCost` should not be a property like this but more something for a service method like
`VehicleService.calculateTotalInsuranceCostForFamily (String familyName)`.

Your family entity then becomes:

```
@Entity
public class Family (  
    @Id
    private String familyName;

    private int size;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "family")
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

    // getters and setters
)
```

Comment: What if I make the VehiclesList as @Entity?  Is there a way to access the Vehicle class from the Family class through VehiclesList class?  You example shows accessing the Vehicle class directly from the Family class, which I want to avoid.

Comment: But VehicleList is no entity (not backed by a DB view or table). Why do you want to avoid this direct access? This is the normal way to do it.